# How to find FMX TSearchBox

Tags: ide, delphi-11-alexandria

I have a multi-device FMX project in Delphi 11. I would like to add a search box to a form, but I cannot find a TSearchBox component in the tool palette. The docs confirm that a TSearchBox component exists. I'm using the WedgewoodLight style (from GetIt) which contains search box related styles (searchboxstyle, searcheditbutton, searchtoolbutton, searchtoolbuttonbordered) but when I place an TEdit on a form none of those styles is displayed in the StyleLookup options for the edit.

The Controls sample app contains a TSearchBox component in a design view. It seems I can copy it to the clipboard but I cannot paste it into my project.

Is there a way to visually add a TSearchBox to my project?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`TSearchBox`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.SearchBox) in the [MobileControls sample](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/FMX.Controls_Sample) is a child component of the [`TListBox`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.ListBox.TListBox). You can add it by right clicking on a `TListBox` and choosing **Add Item** → *TSearchBox*.

[image: Adding a TSearchBox to the TListBox]

If you look in the [`FMX.SearchBox`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.SearchBox) unit, where `TSearchBox` is defined, you will see it implements the [`IListBoxHeaderTrait`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Controls.IListBoxHeaderTrait) interface. It looks like it should work outside a `TListBox`, but you could easily create your own version too of you look at the code.

Interestingly the `TSearchBox` is missing from the **ListBox's Item Editor** dialog, as are about half of the other items...

[image: TListBox Items Editor]